# Django Migration timed out

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have a logging table,which is being continuously written to,in which i want to add a column,it's migration works fine on local but it's getting timed out on deployment

This is the migration file a have:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("request_log", "0004_requestlog2"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="requestlog2",
            name="request_type",
            field=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
                blank=True,
                choices=[(0, "Incoming"), (1, "Outgoing"), (2, "Internal")],
                help_text="State the type on request",
                null=True,
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

This is the migration logs:

```
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying request_log.0005_requestlog2_request_type...django 21/Oct/2022:15:12:54,194347 +0000 [INFO] squadrun.sentry_helpers: thread=140715699507328 extra: exchash: b8ca65d21d0d448f8fe90658c0708923 detected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticapm/instrumentation/packages/dbapi2.py", line 210, in execute
    return self._trace_sql(self.__wrapped__.execute, sql, params)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticapm/instrumentation/packages/dbapi2.py", line 244, in _trace_sql
    result = method(sql, params)
psycopg2.extensions.QueryCanceledError: canceling statement due to statement timeout


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 40, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/schema.py", line 69, in add_field
    super(PostGISSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 396, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 446, in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticapm/instrumentation/packages/dbapi2.py", line 210, in execute
    return self._trace_sql(self.__wrapped__.execute, sql, params)
  File "/storage/.pyenv/versions/3.5.9/envs/squadrun_python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticapm/instrumentation/packages/dbapi2.py", line 244, in _trace_sql
    result = method(sql, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: canceling statement due to statement timeout

Sentry is attempting to send 0 pending error messages
Waiting up to 2 seconds
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

This is the Query which query which is getting timed out:

`ALTER TABLE "request_log_requestlog2" ADD COLUMN "request_type" smallint NULL CHECK ("request_type" >= 0)`

my best guess is that “ALTER TABLE” command is trying to get a lock on the entire table
but since the table is being continuously written to, it’s not able to get the lock in time

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Simple solution is to bring the site down and run the migrations.  I would make doing such a step part of the deployment process

Comment: downtime is not an option here i believe it's waiting to acquire the lock to perform alter statement but statement is timed out before acquiring the lock,is there way in django where we can run migrate command with custom statement_timeout parameter?

Comment: If you have code that is dependent on the new table structure, then how are you handling the downtime with deploy?  If there is not a corresponding code change, then you can modify the db from a non-django process or using a Postgres Management tools.  It seems like you are misusing migrations